# Hibernate get object from database where date equals a given date

Tags: hibernate, date, hql

I want to get a list of objects from the database between a given date time range. How do I achieve that ? This is the solution I am currently using, but it doesn't return anything... and the given values are correct.

```
public List getRegistrationsForUserOnDate(Date startdate, Date enddate){
        Set<Date> dateSet = new HashSet<Date>();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(enddate);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(startdate))
        {
            Date resultado = calendar.getTime();
            dateSet.add(resultado);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        String query = "from Registration where date = '" + Validation.convertToValidDateTime(startdate, true) + "'";
        for(Date date : dateSet){
            query += " AND date = '" + Validation.convertToValidDateTime(date, true)+"'";
        }             
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();           
    }
```

for example:

```
startdate  = Fri Jun 15 12:07:31 CEST 2012

enddate = Wed Jun 13 12:07:31 CEST 2012
```

Then this methods query looks like this (data copied from debug mode):

```
from TimeRegistration where date = '2012-06-15 00:00:00' AND date = '2012-06-14 00:00:00' AND date = '2012-06-13 00:00:00'
```

These are some sample fields that are present in the database:

```
id |       date          |comment|FK|FK|FK
132|"2012-06-08 00:00:00"|    "" | 6| 2| 1
133|"2012-06-15 00:00:00"|    "" | 8| 1| 1
134|"2012-06-14 00:00:00"|    "" | 3| 2| 1
135|"2012-06-13 00:00:00"|    "" | 1| 3| 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can date equal two different dates? Not surprised you don't get anything.

date = '2012-06-15 00:00:00' AND date = '2012-06-14 00:00:00' - so if todays date is thursday and friday return it?

Should you be using OR rather than AND, or better still, greater and less than or between?

```
from TimeRegistration where date between '2012-06-13 00:00:00' and '2012-06-15 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Ah.. yes stupid me.. I tried using the OR clause but that also doesnt work.. any other suggestions ?

Comment: Exact matches on dates can be problematic. Unless there is some pressing requirement that your date be exactly in that second, I would do a between or date >= '2012-06-13 00:00:00' and date <= '2012-06-15 00:00:00'. I would also say check it works on the database before editing the code!

Comment: I am using this query ATM and it works on the database: select * from tbl_registrations where date in ('2012-06-15 00:00:00', '2012-06-14 00:00:00', '2012-06-13 00:00:00') But when i implement this in my code it suddenly doesnt work anymore

Comment: this is the query that is send from within my method: from Registration where date in ('2012-06-15 00:00:00', '2012-06-14 00:00:00', '2012-06-13 00:00:00')

Comment: And you are sure your date format is as you expect, and that 'date' is a property in the object that you are reading? Can you look at the log of the database to see what is really coming out?

Comment: nothing is comming out, and i just copied the 'query' from the debug mode into my database query launcher and put 'select *' in front of it and changed the objectname tot he tablename and that returns exactly what i want

Comment: What I meant is the actual low level query, not the hql but the actual SQL. HQL changes the names of the tables depending on the name of the class that matches the table. Check on the sql log itself (if you have one). Also try without dates to make sure it comes up with something, and make sure you try between dates, rather than the specific time (or search for a specific date with a Date() sql function).

Answer (score 0):

### HQL:

```
from objectname where date in ('date1','date2','date3')
```

### result:

### *returns all objects where their date attribute equals date1 or date2 or date3.*

*I now use the following method I created where you only have to declare a start and an end date and it gets all the objects on the dates between those two dates and it works like a charm.*

```
public List getRegistrationsForUserOnDate(Date startdate, Date enddate)throws Exception{
        Collection<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(enddate);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(startdate)){
            Date resultado = calendar.getTime();
            dateList.add(resultado);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

            String query = "from Registration t where t.date in ('" + Validation.convertToValidDateTime(startdate, true) + "'";
            for(Date date : dateList){
                query += ", '" + Validation.convertToValidDateTime(date, true)+"'";
            }
            query += ")";

            return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        }
```

this is my Validation.convertToValidDateTime method source, have fun!:

```
public static String convertToValidDateTime(Date date, boolean clearTime)throws Exception{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatRemoveTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return clearTime
                ?dateFormat.format(dateFormatRemoveTime.parse(dateFormatRemoveTime.format(date)))
                :dateFormatRemoveTime.format(date);
    }
```